# If_else e Filter

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

To tentando dar um `filter`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

filter(indicesBrutos, if_else(day(NomDataIn) != 1, 
                                     filter(Mes >= NomDataIn-30, Mes <= CMData)),
              filter(Mes >= NomDataIn, Mes <= CMData))
```

Aparece isso:

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") :    no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"

Dados:

```
structure(list(Mes = structure(c(6971, 6999, 7030, 7060, 7091, 
7121), class = "Date"), Indice = c("BTN", "BTN", "BTN", "BTN", 
"BTN", "BTN"), VarPerc = c(3.6, 6.090733, 7.305977, 9.937256, 
24.834181, 28.7656), Fator = c(1.036, 1.06090733, 1.07305977, 
1.09937256, 1.24834181, 1.287656), Selic_Perc_Ano = c(7.0237, 
8.2886, 2.7003, 2.6646, 17.0939, 30.0523), JM_Mes = c(0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Leia a ajuda para formatação de código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Explique o seu problema e o resultado que espera. "Tentando dar um filter" é amplo demais,

Comment: E onde está a variável `NomDataIn`?

Comment: Agradeço as respostas. Neves, peço escusas pela minha má explicação, tentarei melhorar. Consegui pelo if else normal.

Answer (score 4):

Segue a resolução encontrada:

```
indices <- if (day(NomDataIn) != 1) {
  filter(indicesBrutos, Mes >= NomDataIn-30, Mes <= CMData)
} else {
  filter(indicesBrutos, Mes >= NomDataIn, Mes <= CMData)
}
```

Quanto às variáveis `NomDataIn` e `CMData`, elas correspondem a datas no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`.